# Average every three dataframe rows starting from the previous row

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe

I am wondering how I can find the average of every three rows such that the following three row average starts from the previous row value. In other words, the following three row average starts from the last row of the previous three row average. Consider this example table:

```
    Time                 Value      
0   11/22/2013 8:30      0
1   11/22/2013 9:00      1 
2   11/22/2013 9:30      2
3   11/22/2013 10:00     6
4   11/22/2013 10:30     8
    ...                  ...
```

The desired result for the example table would be:

```
     Time                Value      
0    11/22/2013 9:00    1 
1    11/22/2013 10:00   5.333
     ...                 ...
```

In this case, the first three-row average is an average of rows 0, 1, and 2 from the original table. The second three-row average is an average of rows 2, 3, and 4 from the original table. Hence, the value is an average of 2, 6, and 8, which is 5.33 while the datetime is 10:00.

Unfortunately, I only know how to find three row averages using the following code. However, I am interested in finding three row averages that starts from the last row of the previous three row average.

```
idx = len(df)
df.groupby(df.index[:idx] // 3).mean()
```

Comment: when averaging you are taking rows 0,1,2 then 2,3,4 why is that? either its 0,1,2 then 1,2,3 etc or 0,1,2, then 3,4,5 so what exactly are you doing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
ans = {"Time": [], "Value": []}

for i in range(1, len(df)-1, 2):
    ans["date"].append(df.loc[i, "date"])
    ans["Value"].append(sum([df.loc[i+j, "value"] for j in [-1, 0, 1]])/3)

new_df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(ans)
```

Comment: Thank you, the "value" part of the code works as intended! However, the Date column only produces the time stamp from row 1 of the original table.

Comment: Oh, thanks for pointing that out. I mistakenly wrote `df.loc[1, "date"]` instead of `df.loc[i, "date"]`. Fixed it now :)